# Asset pricing and dividend discount model

Tags: asset-pricing, dividends, derivation

I want to derive the dividend discount model from the asset pricing formula described in "Efficient Capital Markets: A Review of Theory and Empirical Work" by Eugene Fama 1970. The formula that I am referring to is equation number 1:

[image]

What I could do so far is the following:

[image]

As you can see I separated the asset price today as a function of future price discounted. The phi represents the information in the market about the price, risk etc. If we are pricing a share, we can consider the future price the sum of all the discounted dividends to today, therefore we can rewrite to the following:
[image]

Is this correct? If extra information is needed I will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Line (4) is true, but it does not follow from line (3) since $\frac{\operatorname{E}[A]}{\operatorname{E}[B]} = c$ does not imply $\operatorname{E}[\frac{A}{B}] = c$. Line (5) is missing the the expectation operator and has a got a confused notion of discounting going on inconsistent with previous definitions for $r_{j, t+1}$.